# Android BLE Advertisement fails with error code 1

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a sample app that is using BLE to advertise some data.  However, my Advertisement fails with error code 1.  Error code 1 basically means that the payload is bigger than the allowed 31 bytes for the advertisement packet. But from my code, I can see that the payload is less than 31 bytes.  Where is the issue?

Some suggested turning off device name advertisement as a long name will take space. I have done that as well.

```
private void advertise(){
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser =         BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
            .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setConnectable( false )
            .build();
    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString( getString( R.string.ble_uuid ) ) );
    //ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.randomUUID() );


    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)

            .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
            .addServiceData( pUuid, "D".getBytes() )
            .build();
    advertiser.startAdvertising( settings, data, advertisingCallback );
}
```

I expect this to advertise data "D", not fail with error code 1.

Comment: What does R.string.ble_uuid contain?

Comment: <string name="ble_uuid">CDB7950D-73F1-4D4D-8E47-C090502DBD63</string>

Comment: can you tell me how you are receiving data at the other end? I am having trouble getting correctly encoded data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like you are adding pUuid to the advertisement data twice. Once by itself and a second time with the data "D". BLE advertisements only have room for 1 UUID. Try eliminating that first call to:

```
.addServiceUuid(pUuid)
```

and instead only use:

```
.addServiceData(pUuid, "D".getBytes())
```

Comment: Looks like you are right! I could have never figured that out!

Comment: @Greg Moens I am using the same example and steps as user3656651 mentioned... Also facing the same issue... I tried the solution which you have answer here but still getting the same error.

Comment: Yep! It works! Just commenting to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

The "serviceDataUuid" is  16-bit only. The method .addServiceData extracts silently a 16-bit UUID from a given 128-bit UUID, if the UUID is from the Bluetooth SIG. From your custom UUID =  CDB7950D-73F1-4D4D-8E47-C090502DBD63, you must create a 16-bit UUID which is within the address range of the Bluetooth SIG.

```
private void advertise(){
    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
            .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setConnectable( false )
            .build();
    //ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString( getString( R.string.ble_uuid ) ) );
    //ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.randomUUID() );
    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString("cdb7950d-73f1-4d4d-8e47-c090502dbd63"));
    ParcelUuid pServiceDataUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("0000950d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));


    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)

            .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
            .addServiceData( pServiceDataUuid, "D".getBytes() )
            .build();
    advertiser.startAdvertising( settings, data, advertisingCallback );
}
```

[Screenshot nRF Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzbK4.png)

Answer (score 1):

I tried both above solution of @Greg Moens and @S. Gysin, and what I found is
You just have to change the `ble_uuid` value `CDB7950D-73F1-4D4D-8E47-C090502DBD63` with `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.

It works for me.

Also you can check the complete blogpost for the same here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426